# XMonad hotkeys (mostly) broken on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, xmonad

I switched from 16.10 to 17.10 and some of my xmonad key bindings stopped working. I'm using default gnomeConfig:

```
main = xmonad $ gnomeConfig
  { workspaces = myWorkspaces
  , modMask = mod4Mask
  }
```

What is still working:

- Mod-Shift-Enter to start terminal
- Mod-Space to change window layout
- Mod-Tab to select windows
- Mod-Enter to set master window

What is NOT working: almost anything else. What I noticed is

- Mod-p to show gnome Run dialog
- Mod-Shift-q to close session
- Mod-t, Mod-j/k, Mod-Shift-j/k, ...

I tried adding bindings for these keys to my config file, but to no avail, they still doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to get rest of the hotkeys working?

I'm using [gnome-session-xmonad](https://github.com/Gekkio/gnome-session-xmonad) package, if this is important.

Comment: Hi, any success?

Comment: Nope. Waiting for the LTS release, maybe fallback to X will fix this.

Comment: 18.04 beta is still useless even with X! :(

Now trying with MATE.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in GNOME Flashback. I've [reported the issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback/issues/11).